# Call python Fabric functions from within the same script

Tags: python, fabric

I have a single file script for operations automation (log file downloads, stop/start several containers. User is choosing what to do via command arguments) and want to have fabric functions in the same script as well as argument parsing class and possibly some other. How do I call fabric functions from within the same python script? I do not want to use "fab" as it is.

And as a side note, I'd like to have these calls parallel as well.

This is a model class that would ideally contain all necessary fabric functions:

```
class fabricFuncs:
  def appstate(self):
    env.hosts = hosts
    run('sudo /home/user/XXX.sh state')
```

This is launcher section:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
  argParser().argParse()
  fabricFuncs().ihsstate()
```

argParser sets variables globaly using command line arguments specified (just to clarify what that part does).
Which sadly results in a failure where no hosts are defined (env.hosts should contain that inside the function...or is it too late to declare them there?)

EDIT1:
I have tried launching the fabric function using this:

```
for h in env.hosts:
  with settings(hosts_string=user + "@" + h):
    fabricFuncs().ihsstate()
```

It kind of works. I kind of hoped though, that I will be able to paralelize the whole process using fabric module as it is (via decorators) without wraping the whole thing in threading code.

EDIT2:
I have tried this as well:

```
  execute(fabricFuncs().ihsstate())
```

Which fails with:

```
Fatal error: Needed to prompt for the target host connection string (host: None)
```

Can i put a whole env.hosts variable into "settings" above without iterating over that list with a "for" statement?

EDIT3:
I have tried editing the fab function like this to see if env.hosts are set properly:

```
class fabricFuncs:
  def appstate(self):
    env.hosts = hosts
    print env.hosts
    run('sudo /home/user/XXX.sh state')
```

And it prints out correctly, but still the "run" command fails with:

```
Fatal error: Needed to prompt for the target host connection string (host: None)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [execute](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.6/usage/execution.html#intelligently-executing-tasks-with-execute) command:

```
from fabric.api import execute

execute(argParser().argParse())
execute(fabricFuncs().ihsstate())
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but it still ends with this:

Fatal error: Needed to prompt for the target host connection string (host: None). arParser().argParse() is a non-fabric function so I left it as it was and added execute to ihsstate() function. I suppose it needs to "execute" the fabric function with some "settings" parameter.

Comment: @panta: yes you need the env.hosts defined. You can first execute an fabric function that defines this, and then call th erest of your scripts.

Comment: Thanks again for your reply, it is much appreciated. I have tried this without success as well. env.hosts are set properly (if I add print env.hosts just before the "run" part of a fabric function, it prints out correctly), but the whole operation still fails with "Needed to prompt for the target host connection string (host: None)". I will edit the question to further describe whats going on inside the fab function.

Comment: I have also tried using roledefs. Setting the var like this: env.roledefs = { 'current' : hosts } and adding a decorator @roles('current') just before the function. Same behaviour occured though.

Answer (score 0):

if you run the script without fab command env.host will set to None.
so if you want to use 'execute' you have to pass also 'hosts' parameter.

try this:

```
from fabric.api import execute, run
if __name__ == "__main__":
   hosts = ["host1", "host2"]
   execute(run('sudo /home/user/XXX.sh state'), hosts=hosts)
```